# FFmpeg installation requiring python uninstallation on Mac

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg

Did `brew install ffmpeg`, installs some packages and gives this error :

> Error: python is already installed from !
>
> Please `brew uninstall python` first."

I have python3.6.5 installed via brew, for using Tensorflow etc. No other python version is installed via brew right now. Why is this error coming up? What version does FFmpeg need?

Earlier I actually uninstalled python and that broke my system in many frustrating ways. I had to delete everything and start over. What is a safer way to get this working?

Comment: ffmpeg itself doesn't require python. Possibly, there's some external lib linked by ffmpeg that requires it. Get a static dated binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/